# filtering our rows based on duplicate column values

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, rows

i have a to do some querys from the mondial database and im stuck on one in particular. 
i have to show one country with the highest DPG per capita from every continent.
(one for europe, one for asia, one for africa etc.)

i can show all the countries from every continent and their gdp per capita with:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT continent.name, country.name, cast(1000000*(economy.gdp/country.population) AS decimal(16,2)) AS dgpPerCapita
FROM country 
JOIN economy ON country.code = economy.country
JOIN encompasses ON economy.country = encompasses.country
JOIN continent ON encompasses.continent = continent.name
WHERE cast(1000000*(economy.gdp/country.population) AS decimal(16,2)) is not null
order by cast(1000000*(economy.gdp/country.population) AS decimal(16,2)) desc
```

but i cant filter out the rows with duplicates in contient.

what im looking for is somthing like this:

```
continent                         DGPPERCAPITA    
Europe             Monaco         156004.89    
Asia               Qatar          125394.62    
America            Bermuda        87177.17    
Australia/Oceania  Australia      64317.35
```

im very new to querys and i've spent alot of time looking for the answer and found this:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT continent.name, country.name, 
cast(1000000*(economy.gdp/country.population) AS decimal(16,2)) AS dgpPerCapita,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY continent.name ORDER BY 
cast(1000000*(economy.gdp/country.population) AS decimal(16,2)) DESC) rn

FROM country 
JOIN economy ON country.code = economy.country
JOIN encompasses ON economy.country = encompasses.country
JOIN continent ON encompasses.continent = continent.name
              ) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

but it gives me some errors.

any help would be greatly appreciate.

the website i use to test my querys is: http://www.semwebtech.org/sqlfrontend/

Comment: Unless you're using MySQL 8+ (unlikely), you can't be using MySQL if you're also using `ROW_NUMBER`.  Please tag with the actual database you are using.

Comment: He probably is using MySQL and that is one of the errors that he is referring too.

Comment: im using the website i linked to test it and i have no idea what version that is, but the error im getting from the last codesnippet is: A database error occured: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined. but thats just one of many, as soon as i fix one error i get another.

Answer (score 0):

I see why you got that specific error, Well the column 'name' is ambiguous for Country and Continent tables, name them differently within the sub-query and you are through. I am not sure of what the other error is that you have mentioned.